# Multiple Key Gestures for custom keyboard shortcuts in WPF

Tags: wpf, keyboard-shortcuts, user-input

Does anyone know if it's possible to have key combinations for keyboard shortcuts in WPF?

Right now if I want to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> as a shortcut I can do the following:

```
InputGestures.Add( new KeyGesture( Key.S , ModifierKeys.Control ));
```

But if I want to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> , <kbd>D</kbd> ... I don't have an overload that takes the <kbd>D</kbd>.  Is there a way to override this an accept combinations?