# Capturing ctrl + multiple key downs

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there an easy way to capture a <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>key1</kbd>, <kbd>key2</kbd> event in a winforms app similar to that in visual studio such as <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>, <kbd>c</kbd> = comment out selected lines?

I am currently overriding my forms `OnKeyDown` event:

```
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyDown(e);

        if (e.Control && e.KeyCode.ToString() == "N")
        {
            //do something...
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would save keys on KeyDown into a list, and remove them at KeyUp, and then check in the list if the wanted set of keys is found every time a KeyDown happens. So you could save key1 and key2 into the list, and if both exist, and e.Control is true, then do your thing. On KeyUp, you would remove the pressed key.

Comment: sounds like you want this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194714/multiple-key-gestures-for-custom-keyboard-shortcuts-in-wpf][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194714/multiple-key-gestures-for-custom-keyboard-shortcuts-in-wpf

Comment: @Kell - That question is for WPF, not winforms.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a combination of keys in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244063/how-to-get-a-combination-of-keys-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The article in the comment may have been for WPF but the idea in it can still be used

Construct a class such as

```
    public class MultiKeyGesture
    {
        private List<Keys> _keys;
        private Keys _modifiers;
        public MultiKeyGesture(IEnumerable<Keys> keys, Keys modifiers)
        {
            _keys = new List<Keys>(keys);
            _modifiers = modifiers;
            if (_keys.Count == 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("At least one key must be specified.", "keys");
            }
        }

        private int currentindex;
        public bool Matches(KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Modifiers == _modifiers && _keys[currentindex] == e.KeyCode)
                //at least a partial match
                currentindex++;
            else
                //No Match
                currentindex = 0;
            if (currentindex + 1 > _keys.Count)
            {
                //Matched last key
                currentindex = 0;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

but ignore the inheritance.

to use it

```
    private MultiKeyGesture Shortcut1 = new MultiKeyGesture(new List<Keys> { Keys.A, Keys.B }, Keys.Control);
    private MultiKeyGesture Shortcut2 = new MultiKeyGesture(new List<Keys> { Keys.C, Keys.D }, Keys.Control);
    private MultiKeyGesture Shortcut3 = new MultiKeyGesture(new List<Keys> { Keys.E, Keys.F }, Keys.Control);

    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyDown(e);
        if (Shortcut1.Matches(e))
            BackColor = Color.Green;
        if (Shortcut2.Matches(e))
            BackColor = Color.Blue;
        if (Shortcut3.Matches(e))
            BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
```

Comment: Hi James - Please let me know the use of second parameter in the constructor MultiKeyGesture. Actually, I want to implement the shortcut CTRL+1+2+1; CTRL+1+2+2; CTRL+1+2+3; CTRL+1+2+4; CTRL+1+2+5 in my WinForms application. After using your MultiKeyGesture class it is working but if I do not press CTRL key it is also working. Please suggest how to implement it.

Comment: Hi @BrijeshKumarTripathi, I've added the implementation for modifiers to the answer. I haven't got the time to test this at the moment, so their may be some small issues

Comment: Thanks James. I have tested and it is working as expected. Upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

If you only have a two key shortcut, like VS does, you could store the last key pressed in a variable.

```
private Keys lastKeyPressed = null;

protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnKeyDown(e);
    if(e.Control && lastKeyPressed != null)
    {
        if(lastKeyPressed == Keys.firstKey && e.KeyCode == Keys.secondKey)
        {
        }
        else if (...) // so on and so forth.
    }
    else if(e.Control)
        lastKeyPressed = e.KeyCode;
}

protected override void OnKeyUp(KeyEventsArgs e)
{
    if(!e.Control)
       lastKeyPressed = null;
}
```

This would do a two key shortcut, and would reset it when the ctrl key is released. This is just untested pseudo code but its the concept of saving the last pressed key when Ctrl is being held then resetting it when ctrl is released that I'm trying to convey.

Answer (score 0):

Call e.Modifiers for control key and e.KeyCode for the combined key.

```
private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   // For Tow Key Shortcut.
   if (e.Modifiers == Keys.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.B)
   {}
   
     // For Triple Key Shortcut.
   if (e.Modifiers.ToString() == (Keys.Shift+", "+Keys.Control) && e.KeyCode == Keys.B)
   {} 
}

// For Form level Key events you must have to set KeyPreview to True;
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.KeyPreview = true;
}
```